# vue svg path with v-for

Tags: svg, vue.js, path, v-for

I am trying to bind the various coordinates in an svg path to data() in vue.js

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500">
       <g>
           <path v-for="n in 50" d="'M0 ' + (n*10) + ' L500 ' + (n*10)" fill="white" stroke="lightgray" />
           <path v-for="n in 50" d="{'M0 ' + (n*10) + ' L500 ' + (n*10)}" fill="white" stroke="lightgray" />
       </g>
</svg>
```

The alternative is to call a method and that works,

```
<path v-for="n in 400" :d="gridy(n)" fill="white" stroke="lightgray" />
```

The gridy() method

```
gridy(n) {
                return "M0" + " " + (n * 10) + " L500 " + (n * 10)
            },
```

Is the way I tried to do this without calling a method incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to [bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) the d attribute of the SVG like so:

```HTML
<path v-for="n in 50" :d="'M0 ' + (n*10) + ' L500 ' + (n*10)" fill="white" stroke="lightgray" />
```

Working example:

```js
new Vue({el: '#app'})
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<main id="app">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500">
       <g>
           <path v-for="n in 50" :d="'M0 ' + (n*10) + ' L500 ' + (n*10)" fill="white" stroke="lightgray" />
       </g>
</svg>
</main>
```